# WPF with Unity Container - How to register and resolve ViewModels to Views

Tags: wpf, unity-container

Hi I am trying to use Unity container in WPF MVVM application. I have not used Prism as it seems to heavy. Here is the application structure. I am trying to figure out how to resolve Views to ViewModels and dependencies of the view models (services).

## Application:

Views

```
MainWindow.xaml
CustomerList.xaml
CustomerDetail.xaml
BookList.xaml
BookDetail.xaml
```

ViewModels

```
MainViewModel

CustomerListViewModel

BoolListViewModel

BookDetailViewModel

CustomerDetailViewModel
```

Library

```
ICustomerService (AddCustomer, SaveCustomer, GetCustomers, GetCustomer)

CustomerService:ICustomerService

IBookService (GetBooks, GetBook)

BookService:IBookService

IBookReserveService(Reserve, Return)

BookReserveService:IBookReserveService
```

1. MainViewModel needs reference to ICustomerService, and IBookService
2. CustomerListViewModel needs reference to ICustomerService
3. BoolListViewModel needs reference to IBookService
4. BookDetailViewModel needs reference to ICustomerService, and IBookReserveService
5. CustomerDetailViewModel needs reference to ICustomerService, and IBookReserveService

I have getter setter property for services in each viewmodels.

I am running into issues on how do I use Dependency Injection with WPF especially for Views and ViewModel. I tried with Unity to register and resolve in a console application which is working fine. But I would like some ideas on how this could be done for WPF app. I tried registering

```
 container.RegisterType<ICustomerService, CustomerService>()
 container.RegisterType<IBookReserveService, BookReserveService>()
 container.RegisterType<IBookService, BookService>()
```

and resolve it using 
    container.Resolve();

But I was not sure how I could tell which view must use which view model and resolve them when required and not when the app starts. Also, I dont to resolve all mapping in the app start. It should be done when the menu (Selecting a customer to view detail, selecting a book to view detail, save customer, reserve book etc.) is selected.

Mostly what I read wanted to use IView and IViewModel. But not sure I understood the advantage in it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using Prism would really simplify this entire process for you, as it's in charge of creating your views with your IoC container (Unity in your case). Maybe this question could help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8617277/389966

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's one way you can do this.  First, register your view-models and services with Unity like this:

```
// Unity is the container
_container.RegisterType<IMainViewModel, MainViewModel>();
_container.RegisterType<IBookService, BookService>();
```

Second, set your view's DataContext to a view-model in the view's constructor like this:

```
public partial class MainView:UserControl
{
   private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

   public MainView(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _container = container;   
            this.DataContext = _container.Resolve<IMainViewModel>();            
        }      
}
```

Third, you'll need to inject your services into your view-models:

```
public MainViewModel(ICustomerService custService, IBookService bookService ){}
```

There are other ways to do this using .config files, etc. but this should give you enough to get started, let me know if you need more.  You asked what the advantages of DI are and there are many, I feel.  Just to name a couple:  promotes loose-coupling between your components and improved testability.  I feel it's one of the lynch-pins to a good design/implementation.

UPDATE:

With Unity >=3, you can skip the container registration if you follow the naming convention like this:

```
// This will register all types with a ISample/Sample naming convention 
            container.RegisterTypes(
                AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
                WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
                WithName.Default);
```

Comment: _container, where is it created? I assume it is in App.xaml.cs. How will I have access to this in the view models to resolve it?

Comment: Unity will resolve itself, so no need to register the container with itself.  I've updated my answer to answer your question.

Comment: Perfect. This worked. I also started creating a separate class just to register and resolve types when needed and I made it static instead of passing the container all around. Do you think it is a good approach?

Comment: Great...Let Unity handle the Resolve<T) and I believe that the Unity container is a singleton by default.  I wouldn't create a separate static class to act as a wrapper because I don't see any advantage to it and think it adds unnecessary bloat (just my opinion).  If you have time, research Prism as it facilitates the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Why do you `_container.Resolve<IMainViewModel>(); ` ConstructorInjection/PropertyInjection?

Comment: The UnitContainer is not a singleton. `public UnityContainer() : this(null)
        {
            this.AddExtension(new UnityDefaultStrategiesExtension());
        }`

Comment: @Legends...I used to use a service locator, but now I use constructor injection almost exclusively.  I could update this, but don't feel it adds anything useful at this time.  Thanks.

Comment: This is just a terrible answer! Passing Unity Container to the Main View instead of a `IMainViewModel`?! Now you have a `Service Locator` anti-pattern going on.