# Dependency injection with Unity on wpf MVVM application

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection

I have been trying to set up dependency injection in a wpf application using Unity, but can't seem to fully understand how the views and viewmodels should be set up.

Have looked into another SO post --> [Wpf Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480387/wpf-with-unity-container-how-to-register-and-resolve-viewmodels-to-views) but can't seem to understand it quite yet. I have used Unity before, but just in a MVC application, so I know how to inject it in the contructors.

Here is my views and viewModels in the application.

**Views:**

```
MainWindow.xaml
BookingView.xaml
ContactDetailsView.xaml
ReservationsView.xaml
```

**ViewModels:**

```
MenuViewModel (MainWindow uses this viewModel)
BookingViewModel
ContactViewModel
ReservationsViewModel
```

My ViewModels all have Interfaces implemented, like IMenuViewModel, should the view also have an interface?

I guess that since the MainWindow is the starting point, it should be here to register the container right?

## Update:

Have found something, but not sure if I have done it right. Here is what I have done so far!

1: Using startup method in app.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IViewMainWindowViewModel, MainWindow>();
        container.RegisterType<IViewMainWindowViewModel, MenuViewModel>();

        var mainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>(); // Creating Main window
        mainWindow.Show();
    }

}
```

2: Remove uri from start up.

3: Make IViewMainWindowViewModel interface in MainWindow class, the interface is empty.

```
public interface IViewMainWindowViewModel
{

}
```

4: Make a reference to this interface in the MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IViewMainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindow(IViewMainWindowViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
```

5: Also for the MenuViewModel

```
public class MenuViewModel : IViewMainWindowViewModel
{
    Code not shown!
}
```

This will not even start the application..

## Update 2

My MainWindow class look like this:

```
public interface IViewMainWindowViewModel
{

}

public partial class MainWindow : Window, IViewMainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindow(IViewMainWindowViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
```

App class now look like this:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IViewMainWindowViewModel, MainWindow>();
        container.RegisterType<IViewMainWindowViewModel, MenuViewModel>();
        container.Resolve<MainWindow>().Show();
        //Do the same actions for  all views and their viewmodels
    }
```

I get an exception on this line when running the application

```
container.Resolve<MainWindow>().Show();
```

## Update 3

In my MenuViewModel it has two command which will open two views, do I then need to inject those views in the MenuViewModel's constructor or can you just make another empty interface between MenuViewModel and BookingView as an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me show an example with explanations just for your `MainWindows`, as for the rest views and viewmodels steps to do are the same.

At first, you should create a contract between `View` and `ViewModel`. It shoud be some interface and let it call IViewMainWindowViewModel **(keep in mind that name has to be different for other view and viewModels, for example IViewBookingViewViewModel):**

```
public interface IViewMainWindowViewModel
{
       /*This interface should not have any methods or commands. It is just 
       contract between View and ViewModels and helps to decide to Unity 
       container what it should inject(appropriate viewModel to necessary 
       View)*/
}
```

then in your viewmodel we should implement this interface:

```
public MenuViewModel:IViewMainWindowViewModel
{}
```

The view should inject this interface `MainWindows.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class MainWindows : UserControl, IContentAView
{
    public MainWindows(IViewMainWindowViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;            
    }
 }
```

Delete `StartupUri` and override a method `OnStartup` in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IViewMainWindowViewModel, MainWindow>();
    container.RegisterType<IViewMainWindowViewModel, MainWindowViewModel >();
    container.Resolve<MainWindow>().Show();
    //Do the same actions for  all views and their viewmodels
}
```

Comment: Hey. did you look at my Update before writing? i'm not sure i follow with the IViewMainWindowViewModel?

Comment: @Mikkel , you forgot to register view and his interface

Comment: Could you try read from step 1 to 4 again.. explain if this is right or wrong.
In MenuViewModel I can't use DataContext and set it when the Booking command is fired.

Comment: @Mikkel  man, just do how I've shown. Your interface 'IMenyViewModel' should not have any methods or commands. It is just contract between View and ViewModels and helps to decide to Unity container what it should inject(appropriate viewModel to necessary View)

Comment: Okay, I will give it a try.. Just don't get the naming.. will update asap of what I do!

Comment: Now I did what you wrote, but this not even working at all :( what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I should have done what you told me to do.. only my MainWindow only implements the empty interface, but not UserControl, IContentAView 

Dont know if thats important.

Comment: @Mikkel I've made an exampe for you https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D6BDF30773C16E01!2075&authkey=!AEXw2s0xaks9ekw&ithint=file%2crar

Comment: I think its a package I need.. I don't have the package prism.. What do you use?

Comment: .Mikkel see the folder `Prisn v4`. Actually, it is better to use Prism V6, but I.ve used `Prism v4` for this example. The code for `Prism v6` is the same.

Comment: Found the problem, it was in the MenuViewModel where I tried to inject something.. 

Now when I want to inject a view in the constructor in the MenuViewModel, should I then just create a interface between those two? please see Update 3.

Comment: @Mikkel create new interfaces for each view and its viewmodel. Always.